# List<T>.Contains(T) Method seems to return true for substrings? I don't want that

Tags: unity, c#, audio

so I need to check a List of strings belonging to an AudioManager script, *from another script*, to see if it contains a specific string. Accessing that List wasn't hard. What's surprising me is that the method `List<T>.Contains(T)` is returning `true` when it should return `false`. I think this is because it returns true when a *substring* in the List matches the string I am checking for.

My first idea was to just run a for-each loop, but I assumed that was naiive; that I should use a List method. Should I just use a for-each loop? Here are the offending scripts:

This script is on my GameManager prefab. It has the `AudioManager` tag and the script is called `AudioManager.cs.`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static AudioManager instance = null; // static (class level) variable
    public static AudioManager Instance { get { return instance; } } // static getter (only accessing allowed)

    public List<string> anims_w_soundFX;

    public AudioSource bgm;
    private Scene currentScene;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }

        else
        {
            if (this != instance) { Destroy(gameObject); }
        }
        currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();

        anims_w_soundFX = new List<string>()
        {
            "Luigi_Jump_start_wSound",
            "Luigi_Jump_down_wSound",
            "Luigi_Jump_end_wSound",
            "Luigi_Walk_wSound",
            "Luigi_Run_wSound",
            "Luigi_Battle_Punch_wSound",
            "Luigi_Battle_PunchTimed_wSound"
        };
        //@StackExchange users: ^ THIS IS ALL YOU NEED TO READ FOR THIS SCRIPT!
    }

    //(...) there's more but it only affects background music
}
```

This next script is called `SFX_Event.cs`. I use the `SetSFX()` function from this script when I place an animation event on an animation clip:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SFX_Event : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator anim;
    private AnimatorClipInfo[] currentClipInfo;
    private AudioClip sfxClip;
    private GameObject audioManager;
    private List<string> anims_w_soundFX;
    public AudioSource source;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        audioManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("AudioManager");
        anims_w_soundFX = audioManager.GetComponent<AudioManager>().anims_w_soundFX;
    }
    public void SetSFX()
    {
        currentClipInfo = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0);
        string ccName = currentClipInfo[0].clip.name;
        if (anims_w_soundFX.Contains(ccName))
        {
            switch (ccName)
            {
                case "Luigi_Jump_start_wSound":
                    sfxClip = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("SFX/smrpg_jump");
                    PlaySFX();
                    break;

                case "Luigi_Jump_down_wSound":
                    sfxClip = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("SFX/freesfx_falling_quick");
                    PlaySFX();
                    break;

                case "Luigi_Jump_end_wSound":
                    sfxClip = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("SFX/smrpg_click");
                    PlaySFX();
                    break;

                case "Luigi_Walk_wSound":
                    sfxClip = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("SFX/step-floor");
                    PlaySFX();
                    break;

                case "Luigi_Run_wSound":
                    sfxClip = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("SFX/step-floor");
                    PlaySFX();
                    break;

                case "Luigi_Battle_Punch_wSound":
                    sfxClip = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("SFX/smrpg_mario_shell");
                    PlaySFX();
                    break;

                case "Luigi_Battle_PunchTimed_wSound":
                    sfxClip = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("SFX/smrpg_mario_hammer");
                    PlaySFX();
                    break;

                default:
                    Debug.LogError("Something went wrong finding the sfxClip in the cases. Check spelling");
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError(ccName + " isn't known to the AudioManager. Add it to the list in AudioManger.cs");
        }
    }

    private void PlaySFX()
    {
        source.PlayOneShot(sfxClip);
    }
}
```

Now, at runtime, I go nuts with my character and start jumping all over the place. every once in a while, I will see this in my Console:

```
Luigi|Jump_down isn't known to the AudioManager. Add it to the list in AudioManger.cs
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
SFX_Event:SetSFX() (at Assets/Scripts/SFX_Event.cs:70)
```

We shouldn't get far enough to see this error. I don't know how that string (ccName) is being passed or returning false in the first place because

1. That animation doesn't have an Event that calls this script--in fact, it is read-only.
2. I did DUPLICATE that animation, renamed it "Luigi_Jump_down_wSound", and that one DOES have an event pointing to this script, is in the list, and works in another scene. But that animation is not being used by any animation states that get accessed in THIS scene. is Unity *sometimes* confusing the original jump_down animation for the one I duplicated?

I am sorry that this is so complicated.

Comment: This isn't a fix but you might want to add a new list to your SFX class. Something like "public List<SoundEffect> animationSoundEffects;" with an encapsualted class "[Serializable] public SoundEffect { [SerializeField] public string animationClipName; [SerializeField] public string soundClipName; }" that should let you convert your SetSFX() switch statement to a simple for loop and will also help make your code more easy to use once you want to expand it beyond your Luigi character.

Answer (score 0):

so this will frustrate somebody because of the title and all, but I think the problem has nothing to do with substrings and everything to do with (as usual) transitions between animation states that *have* animation events and those that do do not. I am getting error logs for other animation states that have no events in them.

My theory is that an animation that does have the event calling `SetSFX()` transitions to an animation without the event, while that function is called. So it is checking against an animation it should not be.

I can fix this by turning off Exit Time and setting Duration to 0, but my animations will be jankier. I will have to think how I want to resolve this. It isn't actually hurting the game, it is just annoying. That something is quietly misfiring a few times a minute.